# Эффективность конструкторов/операторов для класса с полем any

Tags: c++, конструктор, оператор-присваивания, any

Имею класс Solution, какие поля у него - видно из конструкторов. Вопрос в том, как (если нужно) оптимизировать конструкторы/операторы, приведенные ниже. Например, перемещающий конструктор вызывает перемещающий оператор присваивания, тот в свою очередь вызывает конструктор по умолчанию `Solution()`. Можно ли изменить этот момент, например, вызывая swap в самом конструкторе. С классом `any` ранее не работал, интересует эффективность этих ф-й-членов при работе с ним. Что еще стоит изменить?

```
Solution::Solution() UM_NOEXCEPT :
    m_index         (DEFAULT_INDEX),
    m_probability   (DEFAULT_PROBABILITY),
    m_data          ()
{} // Solution::Solution()

Solution::Solution(const Solution& other) UM_NOEXCEPT :
    m_index         (other.index()),
    m_probability   (other.probability()),
    m_data          (other.data())
{} // Solution::Solution(const Solution& other

Solution::Solution(const any& data, std::double_t probability) UM_NOEXCEPT :
    m_index         (DEFAULT_INDEX),
    m_probability   (probability),
    m_data          (data)
{} // Solution::Solution(const any& data, std::double_t probability)

Solution::Solution(Solution&& other) UM_NOEXCEPT
{
    *this = std::move(other);
} // Solution::Solution(Solution&& other)

Solution::Solution(any&& data, std::double_t probability) UM_NOEXCEPT :
    m_index         (DEFAULT_INDEX),
    m_probability   (probability),
    m_data          (std::move(data))
{} // Solution::Solution(any&& data, std::double_t probability)

Solution& Solution::swap(Solution& rhs) UM_NOEXCEPT
{
    using std::swap;

    swap(this->m_index, rhs.m_index);
    swap(this->m_probability, rhs.m_probability);
    swap(this->m_data, rhs.m_data);

    return *this;
} // Solution& Solution::swap(Solution& rhs)

Solution& Solution::operator=(const Solution& rhs) UM_NOEXCEPT
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        Solution(rhs).swap(*this);
    }

    return *this;
} // Solution& Solution::operator=(const Solution& rhs)

Solution& Solution::operator=(Solution&& rhs) UM_NOEXCEPT
{
    rhs.swap(*this);
    Solution().swap(rhs);

    return *this;
} // Solution& Solution::operator=(Solution&& rhs)
```

Comment: any к тому, что конструкторы некоторых классов могут резервировать блок памяти при вызове (например array).

Comment: А вы уверены, что обычный оператор присваивания должен делать именно swap, а не копирование? Потому как тогда его поведение будет похоже на std::auto_ptr, чего пользователи вряд ли будут ожидать. move семантика для того и нужна, чтобы пользователь сам мог решить, копирование ему нужно, или перемещение.  А вот в операторе перемещения `Solution().swap(rhs)` все же может иметь смысл. Нет общепринятого мнения о том, что именно должно происходить с объектом после перемещения, но ваше решение на этот счет обязательно должно быть документировано.

Comment: @ВикторСмирнов так в обычном операторе присваивания и делается swap с временным объектом. Так все зависит от к-ра копирования, т.е. не надо дублировать код. Плюс swap дешево обходится за счет move-семантики.

Comment: @Jenssen, в том то и дело, что swap в обычном операторе присваивания не ожидается и не имеет смысла. Если пользователь хочет переместить объект, а не копировать - он так и напишет: `obj1 = std::move(obj2)`, в результате чего будет вызван оператор перемещения (присваивание с перемещением). Если вы хотите, что бы объект нельзя было копировать, просто запретите оператор присваивания копированием, оставите только перемещение - никакого дублирования кода не будет. Кроме того, поведение оператора присваивания и конструктора копирования должны совпадать, иначе поведение опять же неожиданно.